# Why Is Spark NOT auto-detecting new fields in my Parquet files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

In the excerpt below from the Databricks blog, the claim is made that, as Spark 1.3, if new fields are added over time to a parquet schema, they will be automatically detected and dealt with (I assume by inserting NULLs for that field in the time period BEFORE it was introduced into the parquet files).

This feature is NOT working for me -- for instance if I use this command to read ALL the months of data:

`df=spark.read.parquet('/mnt/waldo/mixpanel/formatted/parquet/')`

and then attempt to query one of the newly added fields, as of August, it is NOT found.

However, if I JUST read that month's data:

`df=spark.read.parquet('/mnt/waldo/mixpanel/formatted/parquet/eventmonth=2018-08-01')`

then that field is there for the querying.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

> In the Apache Spark 1.3 release we added two major features to this source.  First, organizations that store lots of data in parquet often find themselves evolving the schema over time by adding or removing columns.  With this release we add a new feature that will scan the metadata for all files, merging the schemas to come up with a unified representation of the data.  This functionality allows developers to read data where the schema has changed overtime, without the need to perform expensive manual conversions.
>   https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/24/spark-sql-graduates-from-alpha-in-spark-1-3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading Parquet files, you need to specifically ask for the schema to be merged when needed; otherwise as a speed optimization, Spark will only read the schema for the first partition encountered and assume all partitions have the same.

Use:

df=spark.read.option("mergeSchema","true").parquet('/mnt/waldo/mixpanel/formatted/parquet/')

---

Comment: I tried correcting this in an edit, but it was apparently rejected: change 'mergedSchema' to 'mergeSchema' and it works perfectly!  Thanks rluta!

Comment: I've fixed the typo in the option name. Thanks for the feedback.