# How to get data from parquet with updated schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am using AWS Athena + AWS Glue + Parquet in S3
And when I modify schema declared in AWS Glue, Athena does not query new data.
E.g.

```
Schema v1:
one: string
two: string
```

```
parquet file
one: value1
two: value2
```

```
Athena read query:
one: value1
two: value2
```

Then I update schema

```
Schema v2:
one: string
two: string
three: string
```

Upload parquet file with updated schema

```
parquet file
one: value1
two: value2
three: value3
```

For now we have 2 parquet files in the bucket (one, two) and (one, two, three)

```
Athena read query:
one: value1, value1
two: value2, value2
(expected)three: null, value3
(actual)three: null, null
```

The question is why Athena doesn't fetch three column value from parquet file where it really exists (second file) and how to make it work?

During investigation I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925482/why-is-spark-not-auto-detecting-new-fields-in-my-parquet-files) on SO, but it is related to spark, not Athena, and it would be logical to have the same mechanism on Athena (merge on read), but I haven't found it. Could someone explain how to make it work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The recent solution to the classical problem of schema evolution is using [Iceberg with Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-iceberg-evolving-table-schema.html).

```
ALTER TABLE iceberg_table ADD COLUMNS (three string)
```

> Apache Iceberg is an open table format for very large analytic datasets. Iceberg manages large collections of files as tables, and it supports modern analytical data lake operations such as record-level insert, update, delete, and time travel queries. The Iceberg specification allows seamless table evolution such as schema and partition evolution, and its design is optimized for usage on Amazon S3. Iceberg also helps guarantee data correctness under concurrent write scenarios.

For more information about Apache Iceberg, see https://iceberg.apache.org/.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using terraform for creating those resources.
I tried to change type of my table to ICEBERG, e.g.:

Before
`resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "table" {
...
 table_type = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"
  parameters = {
    EXTERNAL              = "TRUE"
    "parquet.compression" = "GZIP"
  }
...
}`
After
`resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "table" {
...
  table_type = "ICEBERG"
  parameters = {
    "parquet.compression" = "GZIP"
  }
...
}`
But got the same result
How can I adjust using iceberg to my approach?

Comment: There are two different events here, first is the CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE (using TF, for example), and the second is the ALTER TABLE to reflect the addition of the column. You need to have both, while the second is not related to TF, and should be using a different API (SQL or Glue).